# Git Merge Conflict Practises

Tags: git, merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I think this is a very small issue but I want to know if there's any actual documentation on the topic one way or another, or maybe even opinions with reasons why.

When dealing with merge conflicts is it better to

1. Commit the merge with ONLY the merge resolution using git, then
   build and test and if you've made mistakes with the merge reset HEAD
   back one and repeat merge resolutions so that the only things
   changed can be traced back to either branch1 or branch2 but it might
   take longer.
2. Resolve the conflicts, remain uncommitted, build and go to editor to fix merge mistakes manually in an IDE, once it builds
   commit the merge. Quicker but not every change is traceable to a
   branch.
3. There are many ways to skin a cat and it doesn't matter if
   the change was or wasn't in either branch before the merge.
4. Another option not listed

Comment: Although this seems like a very reasonable and thought out question, asking for opinion is considered off-topic here at Stack Overflow.

Comment: With that said, other options are to resolve the conflicts and commit. Then when you build and test either 1) `git commit --amend`, 2) commit as normal and leave as-is, or 3) commit as normal `git rebase -i` and squash commits with the merge commit.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really good question, and for the case of rebasing a branch it gets even more complicated.  A single rebase operation may involve recommitting *multiple* commits on top of a target branch.  Each one of these commits could potentially be introducing a bug.  I have never heard of someone doing a full build and test cycle for each commit in either a rebase or a merge.

I would say that best practice is to just make some number of additional commits after a merge or rebase which fixes the bug.  This way, you have a clean audit trail about what actually happened.  Having such a history also helps from a separation of concerns point of view.  If you ever needed to revert a post merge bug fix, using this approach it would be straightforward.  It would be more difficult if you were to roll the bug fix together with the merge commit.